# iPhone Specific CSS

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, mobile, mobile-safari

I've created a specific style sheet for my `Wordpress` site for mobile devices. For some reason the screen is zoomed in at a level where the site is not viewable, and I am unable to pinch zoom out for full screen viewing.

Is there some type of meta tag I need in there for devices? Currently I have this.

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/mobile.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will allow me to edit the style sheet and it will reflect the changes on mobile. How can I get it to zoom out?

Comment: I'd guess your theme has a `<meta name="viewport">` tag with `user-scalable=no` set.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:  initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 metatags

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html